# VBA SUB no object set

Tags: excel, vba

Everything was following the video but somehow it just shows no object set. I wish someone could help me with finding the issue.

[image]

video link: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=gIOj_6mIAR0&ab_channel=ExcelForFreelancers

Comment: What is the issue?  Have you tried `Grp` instead of `GP`?  Like `YearsGrp`, `MonthsGrp`, etc.  Your code has `Years GP` and `MonthsGP` which isn't the same as the video.

Comment: Could you describe the problem without a link to an outside site?

Answer (score 0):

You can check your Shape objects with something like the following:

```
Public Sub ListShapes()

Dim ws As Worksheet ''' Create Worksheet class object
Dim sh As Shape ''' Create Shape class object

Set ws = ActiveSheet ' Or: Set ws = Worksheets("Sheet1")


''' Iterate a print name of all shapes on the worksheet
For Each sh In ws.Shapes
    Debug.Print sh.Name
Next sh

''' Clear up objects when done. Not super necessary, but it can be helpful at times.
Set sh = Nothing
Set ws = Nothing

End Sub
```

Then you should be able to see which objects have which names on your worksheet.

You can also hit `ALT + F10` to see the Selection pane (should appear at the right of the worksheet) and that will have a list of objects on the worksheet:

[image]